# How to do tokenizing by n-gram for pdf file in R

Tags: r, tokenize, text-mining, tidytext

I want to tokenize a pdf document by ngrams in R.
I tried to follow the instructions here 
 at https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html,
but get stuck with the `unnest_tokens()` function.

```
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)


filedoc <- "Document2019.pdf"
cname <- file.path(filedoc)
docs <- Corpus(URISource(cname), readerControl=list(reader=readPDF, language = "en")) 

docs_bigrams <- docs %>%
  unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 2)
```

I keep getting this error message:
`Error in UseMethod("unnest_tokens_") : no applicable method for 'unnest_tokens_' applied to an object of class "c('VCorpus', 'Corpus')"`

Is there anything I need to do before running the unnest_tokens function?
Thank you.

Comment: this is not reproducible without Document2019.pdf.

Comment: Use `pdftools::pdf_text()` instead of  `Corpus` to read the pdf. It returns a character vector which you can put in a tibble and use with tidytext.

Comment: Either do as @JBGruber suggests or use the `tidy` function before `unnest_tokens`. Tidytext uses the tidy function to transform from tm objects to tibbles.

Comment: Thanks pals! I go with @phiver's suggestion, using `tidy` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go with @phiver's suggestion, using tidy function, and repost the answer here so that this thread can be closed/answered.

> "use the tidy function before unnest_tokens. Tidytext uses the tidy function to transform from tm objects to tibbles."

Thanks!